# Measuring CPU usage rendering a UIView in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a view on a nib in Interface Builder. It's got a several `UIStackViews` within the nib, which I used because it's a easy to align UI elements. A colleague suggested I not use `UIStackViews` because they're "expensive" from a computational standpoint. The alternative is setting constraints for individual elements manually.

What Xcode tool can I use to validate my colleague's assertion and how would I use it? The best thing I've found is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/tools_profiling_and_debugging/gpu_activity_monitors/monitoring_your_app_s_graphics_activity), but I was hoping for something a little more granular. The nib in question is a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but, your colleague is spectacularly, staggeringly, amazingly, wrong  :)

Comment: @Fattie Different people I talk to have different opinions on this. I was hoping to find a tool that would objectively tell me who's right and who's wrong.

Comment: By all means, I want to know the tool.   Regarding the performance, the handful of basic math calculations involved are stunningly irrelevant.  (if anyone gives you a "different opinion" on that, they can't estimate things within 7 orders of magnitude  :)  :)  )  Again yes it's a great question and hopefully someone brings a great answer!

Comment: Just check the FPS meter in Xcode while scrolling. If you are at smooth 60 fps you don’t have to worry about it. If not you need to dig deeper using instruments what is causing the lags. Might not even be auto layout.

Comment: @Fattie Got my answer. I'm not happy about it, either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In digging around, I found a repo called [LayoutFrameworkBenchmark](https://github.com/layoutBox/LayoutFrameworkBenchmark). I ran the benchmarks in iOS 12 on an iPhone 7+ simulator. I gathered the data and dumped it in a Google Sheet. It does indeed show `UIStackView` is pokey versus other layout methods.

I now see why there seem to be people in both camps, however in the real world, the human eye is unlikely to notice much of a difference unless it's a huge collection.[image]

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be the same as "autolayout" (but .. everything is autolayout?)  I actually don't know what the other entries are on the left??  :O

Comment: @Fattie I had the same question. Most, if not all, are on GitHub. I like PinLayout.

Answer (score 2):

> they're "expensive" from a computational standpoint

Okay, I will now attempt to demonstrate that that's utterly bogus.

A stack view is not magic. A stack view does not perform any special run-time adjustments. A stack view is just a constraint-maker, no more, no less. So are you. Everything a stack view does, you could do. And the stack view's resulting constraints are exactly the same constraints you would have created yourself (assuming you even know how). Therefore, *the constraints themselves are not more expensive* just because the stack view made them.

So let's talk about the initial generation of the constraints. Well, the stack view generates its constraints by rote. It's just a simple formulaic approach based on the parameters already given by such things as the stack view's settings and (in some cases) the intrinsic content sizes of the arranged subviews. So *it takes effectively no time at all* for the stack view to spit out the constraints that it generates, and it only has to do it once.

So if the generation of the constraints is not expensive, and if the constraints themselves are not expensive, where is the expense? It's nowhere.

Someone might argue that for a particular desired outcome using a stack view is unnecessarily complicated, or lazy, so it would have been "better" to make the constraints yourself; but "expensive" doesn't seem to me to be a genuine charge that can be laid against stack views.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. In watching a [2018 WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220), at the 28:08 mark, Apple's rep says they're working on a tool that measures auto layout performance and she demonstrates a non-public version of it.  As of today, I'm not seeing it in Instruments :( Thank you for your insight on this topic.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of WWDC is aspirational. That tool never came to fruition. But you don’t need it. You have the tools to see the constraints created by a stack view, and they are identical to what you would have created, so where is the expense?

Comment: There were quite a few benchmarks out showing that stack views were slower than constraints created manually. I can’t find them right now, so maybe that is not the case any more. Never investigated this, because it was never an issue for me. My only guess would be that stack views create more constraints than one would do manually.

Comment: @Sven If you manage to dig them up, I'd love to see them. For now, I tend to be in Matt's camp. Creating constraints manually when a stack can do them for you in a fraction of the time with a fraction of the effort and nearly flawless results almost feels like "fighting the compiler" to me.